# rails select records which have duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For my case i want to select all duplicates records from table

for example

```
table1 

id | name | sub_name

1  | joe  | j1
2  | tim  | t1 
3  | ben  | b1    
4  | joe  | j2    
5  | tim  | t2
```

i vant to select

```
 [#<table1 id: 1, name: "joe", sub_name: "j1">, #<table1 id: 4, name: "joe", sub_name: "j2">, #<table1 id: 2, name: "tim", sub_name: "t1">, #<table1 id: 5, name: "tim", sub_name: "t2">]

 and then display

 joe
  - j1
  - j2
 tim
  - t1
  - t2
```

Can anybody help me to do this using AR or SQL.

i tried this query `Table1.group(:name).having("count(*) > 1"`

but the result was

`[#<table1 id: 1, name: "joe", sub_name: "j1">, #<table1 id: 2, name: "tim", sub_name: "t1">]`

or `result.count` returns

`{["joe]=>2, ["tim"]=>2}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't know if this is the most efficient way but you could:

```
names_with_multiple_rows = Table1.group(:name).having("count(*) > 1")
res = names_with_multiple_rows.inject({}) do |h, m|
  h[m.name] = Table1.select(:sub_name).where(name: m.name)
  h
end
```

Now res is a hash where the keys is the name and the values are the sub_names.

Comment: thanks Erez, your answer works well. probably exist more clearest solution for this case, but, i dont know.